# Non-linear regression with simulation as forward model (MATLAB)

Tags: matlab, non-linear-regression

I am trying to use the build-in non-linear regression function from MATLAB to perform inverse problem solving and find the parameter that will lead to the best fit of the real data.

I already wrote a function: forwardModel(kGuess) that will take a guess as the input, and run the simulation. This function will generate a vector of data.

So I used the function as my forward model and put it into the lsqcurvefit function in MATLAB. However, it won't run and generate the error saying there is not enough input. How can I fix this problem? Or is there other better way to perform non-linear regression with simulation as forward model?

Below is part my code that performs non-linear regression, please take a look!

```
kGuess = 300;   %initial guess
options = optimoptions('lsqcurvefit', 'Algorithm', 'levenberg-marquardt');
lb = 10; 
ub = 1000;
[k,resnorm,~,exitflag,output] = lsqcurvefit(forwardModel, kGuess, time, potentialMeasured, lb, ub, options)
hold on;
plot(time, forwardModel(k));
xlabel('time(days)'); ylabel('potential between electrodes(V)');
hold off;
```